# PivotTable Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I'm having trouble to understand how to apply PivotTable Conditional Formatting.

Homepage have a pivottable and a 'Date' filter.

Dataset have columns like:

Provider | Date | OC Number | Invoice Nº | MyCondition (here i wrote a formula where value can be 0 or 1)

I won't use MyCondition as a filter. So I would like to apply colour / flags to 'Invoice Nº' Colmumn if 'MyCondition' value for a invoice is 1 (True). I could put a formula 2 columns away from the pivottable to facilitate but I want to know if I can do it directly using a formula condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data? Can you give us a mockup of the table and data? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I couldn't give more details because the file is in my company an at this moment I'm on my home.

'MyCondition' determines if the day of the week of the invoice date for that line is equal to a specific day of the week AND if the supplier of this invoice exists in a specific range.

I would like to refer to these results (0 or 1) rather than having to rewrite this formula to make the formatting work. But the research I've done on how to use VLOOKUP with conditional formatting is much more focused in **static ranges**...

Comment: You can refer to ths sample: https://trumpexcel.com/apply-conditional-formatting-pivot-table-excel/